# ADODB connection to Access DB not opening in vba

Tags: excel, vba, connection, ado

I am trying to connect to an Access database named Inventory.accdb. I am getting an Authentication error at the line ".Open MyConn". At first I was using the Jet provider, which also does not work. Does anyone know how to overcome this?

```
Set ShDest = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

With cnn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .Open MyConn
End With
```

Comment: It is currently not declared as anything. I have this:

Dim MyConn

with my declarations. What should it be declared as?

Comment: Never mind. I overlooked that, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: For reference, it was:

MyConn = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & TARGET_DB

Where TARGET_DB is a constant holding the name of the Access file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a beginning code:

```
Dim cnn, ShDest 

Set ShDest = Sheets("Sheet1")

'
' open connection to Access:
'
Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" _
  & ";Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & TARGET_DB 
cnn.Open
```